# Android: Convert date to milliseconds

Tags: android, date

I used

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
String time = formatter.format(new Date());
```

to get the time (12.03.2012, 17:31), now i want to convert this time to milliseconds, because i have a file with a couple dates and text, and i want to convert the dates in milliseconds so that i cant add the text in inbox using

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123");
values.put("body", "tekst");
values.put("read", 1);
values.put("date", HERE I MUST PUT A DATE IN MILLISECONDS);     
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

Because i must put a time in milliseconds i must convert the time, does anyone know how?

Let's say I have a time `05.01.2011, 12:45` and want to convert it, how? I want to convert an old time that I have (not to get miliseconds from *current* time).

Comment: A simple Google search would've done the job, just saying.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The simplest way is to convert `Date` type to milliseconds:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
formatter.setLenient(false);

Date curDate = new Date();
long curMillis = curDate.getTime();
String curTime = formatter.format(curDate);

String oldTime = "05.01.2011, 12:45";
Date oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);
long oldMillis = oldDate.getTime();
```

Comment: You dont have understand me, i know this. I want the to convert and old time that i have, not to get miliseconds from current time. Let's say i have a time 05.01.2011, 12:45 and want to convert it, how?

Comment: @Gabrijel Ok, I understand now.  I updated my answer to include what you're after

Comment: `long oldMillis = oldDate.getTime()` this will only convert `12:45` to milliseconds not `05.01.2011, 12:45` as a whole!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I believe you are mistaken.  Test it.

Answer (score 3):

Use your date object and call `date.getTime()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the current time in millis just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: The OP is not looking for current milliseconds, but from an existing date.

Answer (score 1):

```
String Date = "Tue Apr 25 18:06:45 GMT+05:30 2017"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
    Date mDate = sdf.parse(Date);
    long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

} catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .getMillis();

e.g:

```
DateTime dtDate = new DateTime();
dtDate.getMillis()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this method you can Convert your Date Into miliseconds that can be used to add events to the Calender

```
public Long GettingMiliSeconds(String Date)
    {
        long timeInMilliseconds = 0;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        try {

            Date mDate = sdf.parse(Date);
            timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return  timeInMilliseconds;
    }
```

Comment: (1) I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) Are you contributing anything that isn’t already in some other answer?

Comment: 1) i have not worked on Java date and time API till now i'll use for next time 2) i think if you are getting date in different formats from database there is no accorate answer to change date into mili seconds so i decided to add this on this.

Comment: it is a complete method to convert date and time into miliseconds weather in which format you got the datetime .

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and desugaring or ThreeTenABP

I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu, H:mm");
    
    String dateTimeString = "12.03.2012, 17:31";
    
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    long milliseconds = dateTime.atZone(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    
    System.out.println(milliseconds);
```

When I run this in Europe/Zurich time zone, the output is:

> 1331569860000

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.