# Unable to set hide fututre date in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using higher then API 11, here some problem during hide future date:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date());
            return dialog;
            /*return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth,
                    cday);*/
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have problem: **setMaxDate(new Date());**

I get this error:

```
The method setMaxDate(long) in the type DatePicker is not applicable for the arguments (Date)
```

So, Please how to hide future date .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc :

> Sets the maximal date supported by this DatePicker in **milliseconds**
>   since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.

You can do the following :

```
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you read the description of the method it says

```
public void setMaxDate (long maxDate) 
Added in API level 11
Sets the maximal date supported by this DatePicker in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.

Parameters
maxDate  The maximal supported date
```

This means you can't just set a `Date` you have to convert your Date to a `long` value.

You can do it like this:

`new Date().getTime()`

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671085/convert-date-to-miliseconds).